# Does an infinitesimal displacement vector have any direction?

Tags: vectors

(dx)i+(dy)j+(dz)k. I mean how can a direction be assigned to it.Or it can also happen that it approaches a null vector.If direction exists then it must be along the vector (1,1,1). But if that happens then some contradictions arise, like how can the displacement point to one direction and its infinitesimal displacement point to another direction.

Comment: As with any infinitesimal element $dx$, an infinitesimal vector $(dx,dy,dz)$ does not have a particular value, only limiting behaviour. So it's meaningless to ask its direction.

Comment: $dx\neq dy\neq dz$ in general, so the vector can point in any direction.

Comment: We could associate a direction using the difference $P(x+\mathrm dx)-P(x)$, but that's not really the same as $\mathrm dx$ having direction.

Comment: It is possible to define an infinitesimal displacement in a specific direction via, say, $\mbox{d}\vec{s}:=\mbox{d}s\times (x, y, z)^T$, where $\mbox{d}s$ is an infinitesimal scalar quantity, without any contradiction.

Comment: For a full development of this kind of thing, see Nowik and Katz, Differential geometry via infinitesimal displacements, http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.0984

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An infinitesimal vector does, of course, have a direction and does, in general, not approach a null vector. The infinitesimal vector is analogous to the common differential in ordinary calculus. For example, if you have a mass point trajectory in space given by the time dependent vector function $$\vec r(t)=\vec i x(t)+\vec j y(t)+\vec k z(t)$$ then the infinitesimal vector $$d\vec r= \frac {d\vec r(t)}{dt}dt=\vec v(t)dt=[\vec i v_x(t)+\vec j v_y(t)+\vec k v_z(t)]dt=\vec t |\vec v(t)|dt$$ gives the infinitesimal displacement of the mass point on its trajectory at location $\vec r(t)$ during an infinitesimal time $dt$ with the direction of the unit vector of momentary tangent or velocity given by $$\vec t=\frac {\vec v(t)}{|\vec v(t)|}$$ which can point in any direction, and is, in general, not zero.

Comment: But what if we are given a random vector and we just have to extend it infinitesimally in the direction of the given vector. We can't define a velocity function here so how will we proceed?

Comment: Nitin Tiwary - If you have a vector $\vec a$ and extend it infinitesimally in its direction then its direction unit vector is $\frac {\vec a}{|\vec a|}$ so that the infinitesimal vector is $d\vec a= da\frac {\vec a}{|\vec a|}$ where $da$ is the infinitesimal length (absolute value) increase of your vector $\vec a$.